# additional resistance required to produce a potential drop

Tags: resistance, emf

A wire of length 100cm is connected to a cell of emf 2V and negligible internal resistance. The resistance of the wire is 3Ω. The additional resistance required to produce a potential drop of 1 millivolt/m?

The answer is 57 ohms.Could someone explain?

Comment: You might want to read about ohms law.

Comment: Do you mean 1 mV/cm along the wire? That's the only way the given answer makes any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that the requirement is really 1 mV/cm of voltage drop along the wire. Here's one way to get there:

1 mV/cm × 100 cm = 100 mV total drop required.

100 mV / 3 Ω = 33.3 mA of current needs to flow.

2 V cell / 33.3 mA = 60 Ω total resistance is required.

60 Ω total - 3 Ω wire = 57 Ω additional required.